# Common message broker interface for Kafka and ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, activemq-classic

I want to design an interface which would be used for simple sending and receiving messages between spring boot micro services. Any service should be able to autowire the interface and use send/receive methods. The implementation of those methods should depend upon, say application.props file whether it wants to use kafka or activemq. I am not able to come up with a clean design. I was thinking if I could create a custom annotation for it. With whatever spring boot experience I have I am not able to imagine such a design. The skeleton looks like something below but I am not able to see how will I be able to implement this as proper code: beans, switch between kafka/activemq specific annotations and methods, etc. things like that.

Service:

@Autowired
MessageProducer messageProducer

@Autowired
MessageReceiver messageReceiver

MessageProducer   [interface]
public void sendMessage(destination, payload)

MessageReceiver   [interface]
public void receiveMessage(source, payload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could have two implementation classes like `KafkaMessageProducer` and `ActvieMQMessageProducer`. inside `application.properties` you could have config like `messaging.type=kafka` or `messaging.type=activemq` that will specify which messaging communication should application select.

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "messaging.type", havingValue = "kafka")
    public MessageProducer messageProducer() {
        return new KafkaMessageProducer();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "messaging.type", havingValue = "activemq")
    public MessageProducer messageProducer() {
        return new ActvieMQMessageProducer();
    }
}
```

if you want to use both messaging types in the same application (e.g. one service class will use Kafka meanwhile another class will use ActiveMQ), then create two beans (as mentioned above, but with `@Qualifier` and without `@ConditionalOnProperty`). And on each service, that require message producer, specify with `@Qualifier` which implementation you need

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("kafkaMessageProducer")
    public MessageProducer messageProducer() {
        return new KafkaMessageProducer();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("actvieMQMessageProducer")
    public MessageProducer messageProducer() {
        return new ActvieMQMessageProducer();
    }

    @Bean
    public YourService messageProducer(@Qualifier("kafkaMessageProducer") MessageProducer messageProducer) {
        return new YourServiceImpl(messageProducer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also please briefly explain how to handle the callback function for the KafkaMessageListener

Comment: could you please explain in more details what you need to do with callback?

Comment: In the above solution of yours, I would use the sendMessage() method in KafkaMessageProducer implementation class. Similarly there also will be receiveMessage() method in say KafkaMessageReceiver, which is the event handler function... message/payload is received in that. I need access to that payload in different services by calling receiveMessage() method

Comment: in that case you need to return received message from MessageReceiver:  `public Object receiveMessage(source)`. or you could pass consumer as additional argument: `public void receiveMessage(source, Consumer callback)`

Comment: Ok, @Vasyl Sarzhynskyi I did the callback with interface.